# How to let the sortedArrayUsingSelector using integer to sort instead of String?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray

I have some data like this :

1, 111, 2, 333, 45, 67, 322, 4445

```
NSArray *array = [[myData allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

If I run this code, it sorted like this:

> 1, 111, 2,322, 333, 4445, 45, 67,

but I actually want this:

> 1, 2, 45, 67, 111, 322, 333, 4445

How can I implement it? thz u.

Comment: What class are the objects in the array- NSString or NSNumber?

Comment: it is NSString... ...But I don't want to change to NSNumber. It is because it may have some data like "1a".... in future.

Comment: How does 1a sort comared with 1 and 10?

Comment: 1, 1a, 10.... ...Sort the number first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Expanding on Paul Lynch's answer, here's an example I have doing exactly this using a comparison method as a category on `NSString`. This code handles only the case of numbers followed by optional non-numeric qualifiers, but you could extend it to handle cases like "1a10" etc. if desired.

Once you create the category method, you just need to do

`[[myData allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(psuedoNumericCompare:)];`

```
@interface NSString (Support) 
- (NSComparisonResult) psuedoNumericCompare:(NSString *)otherString;
@end

@implementation NSString (Support) 

// "psuedo-numeric" comparison
//   -- if both strings begin with digits, numeric comparison on the digits
//   -- if numbers equal (or non-numeric), caseInsensitiveCompare on the remainder

- (NSComparisonResult) psuedoNumericCompare:(NSString *)otherString {

    NSString *left  = self;
    NSString *right = otherString;
    NSInteger leftNumber, rightNumber;


    NSScanner *leftScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:left];
    NSScanner *rightScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:right];

    // if both begin with numbers, numeric comparison takes precedence
    if ([leftScanner scanInteger:&leftNumber] && [rightScanner scanInteger:&rightNumber]) {
        if (leftNumber < rightNumber)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        if (leftNumber > rightNumber)
            return NSOrderedDescending;

        // if numeric values tied, compare the rest 
        left = [left substringFromIndex:[leftScanner scanLocation]];
        right = [right substringFromIndex:[rightScanner scanLocation]];
    }

    return [left caseInsensitiveCompare:right];
}
```

Comment: That's really amazing. Just Works!

Comment: Works like a charm...great!

Answer (score 15):

You can use NSString's `-[compare:options:]` function and the `NSNumericSearch` option to compare NSStrings numerically, without having to convert them to NSIntegers first (which can be quite expensive, especially in longer loops).

Since you want to use an NSArray, you can use NSSortDescriptor's `+[sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:]` (or the identical `-initWithKey:ascending:comparator:` if you want a pre-retained object) function to do block-based comparisation like this:

```
[NSSortDescritor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"myKey"
                             ascending:NO
                            comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }
];
```

Sorting using this method will give the same results as David's answer, but without having to deal with NSScanner yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own method that returns `NSComparisonResult`.  It can be in a category if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Sort and Simple Solution..

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"
                                                   ascending:YES
                                                  comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                                      return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
                                                  }];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [montharray
                   sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [montharray removeAllObjects];
    [montharray addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];

    NSLog(@"MONTH ARRAY :%@",montharray);
```

Answer (score 0):

David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2757825/3962892) did the trick for me. For what it's worth, I want to share the Swift 1.0 version of the same answer.

```
extension NSString {
    func psuedoNumericCompare(otherString: NSString) -> NSComparisonResult {
        var left: NSString = self
        var right: NSString = otherString
        var leftNumber: Int = self.integerValue
        var rightNumber: Int = otherString.integerValue

        var leftScanner: NSScanner = NSScanner(string: left)
        var rightScanner: NSScanner = NSScanner(string: right)

        if leftScanner.scanInteger(&leftNumber) && rightScanner.scanInteger(&rightNumber) {
            if leftNumber < rightNumber {
                return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
            }
            if leftNumber > rightNumber {
                return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
            }

            left = left.substringFromIndex(leftScanner.scanLocation)
            right = right.substringFromIndex(rightScanner.scanLocation)
        }
        return left.caseInsensitiveCompare(right)
    }
}
```