# Rearranging NSMutableArray with unnatural sort order

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutablearray

I would like to rearrange an `NSMutableArray` in a very particular way. This

`1, 7, 0, 45, 0, 0, 500, 0`

Would become like this

`1, 7, 45, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0`.

Anything that's not 0 (or some special value) should be sorted normally at the beginning, with the 0s at the end. How would I do this?

This is going to be used for deletion of a cell from a table view, my table works so that cell index will always point to element in an array. If I leave a blank space the index would no longer lineup with the array.

Comment: You can't have `nil` in an array - what is actually in your array?

Comment: Well that's sorting; just with some sort of weird ass order. There are lots of examples of doing that on this site.

Comment: This link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649850/sorting-array-in-increasing-order

Comment: Thought I'd say that it's objects not numbers, I'm using it for deletion

Comment: You should show your real problem or you will receive answers solving a different problem...

Comment: Seems like filtering might make more sense in this case. Futher to Wain's comment, see [What is the X/Y problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort something like

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(NSNumber *obj1, NSNumber *obj2) {
  if ([obj1 isEqualToNumber:@0]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  } else if ([obj2 isEqualToNumber:@0]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  }

  return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to iOS and Objective-c how would I use this

Comment: Show the code you have and then I can show how it fits in

Comment: I haven't attempted yet, I'm more looking for the therory. (they are objects not numbers)

Comment: What does it return. (NSOrderedAcending. Ect)

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:) the blocks return will be of type `NSComparisonResult` -> `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry simply using `removeObjectAtIndex:` worked well for what I wanted. `removeObjectAtIndex:` shifts all objects by offsetting their index by -1. If anyone needs to keep the `0`'s at the end then you could just add them after deleting them.