# Sorting an NSArray of numerical values puts 99 after 278

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray

I am using the method `[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` with an `NSArray` that contains a lot of numbers.

When I don't use this function they get printed as:

```
99,
161,
278,
179,
180,
189,
182,
125
```

As you can see they are not ordered.

And when I actually use the function, they get printed as:

```
125,
161,
179,
180,
182,
189,
278,
99
```

They are ordered now, but the problem here is that the `99` stays at the end! Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752992/how-to-let-the-sortedarrayusingselector-using-integer-to-sort-instead-of-string

Comment: Your array does not contain numbers. It contains strings. Big difference.

Comment: So, how does it ordered all the numbers? Except the 99 of course.

Comment: Because all of your strings are 3 characters (except the 99). If you had `099` it would sort correctly. But not because they are numbers but because the character "2" comes after "1", etc.

Comment: So, you are telling me that when the number reaches 4 characters, it will be first that the ones with 3 characters? like: 1000, 998, 999...? instead of: 998, 999, 1000?

Comment: "1000" will appear before any string that begins with a 2-9 and even strings like "11". You need to understand the difference between sorting an actual number (`NSNumber') and a string ('NSString'). Strings are simply sorted alphabetically based on the Unicode value of each character in the string. Unless you use special sort options to treat the strings as numbers.

Comment: But since I am using the `[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` method, if you check the documentation, it actually compares  a `NSNumber` not a `NSString`, so it must mean that my `NSArray` contains `NSNumber`s not `NSString`s. Am I right?

Comment: No. `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` uses the provided selector against whatever objects are in the array. Many classes support the `compare:` method including `NSString`. If your array actually had `NSNumber` objects then they would sort as expected. Your output clearly indicates that you have `NSString` objects in your array.

Comment: I've just changed the  `NSString` to `NSNumber` so now the `NSArray` contains `NSNumber`s, but it still makes the same error when applying the function.

Comment: A more powerful way of sorting a list of NSString to use things like NSNumericSearch :

NSArray *sortedArrayOfString = [arrayOfString sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
        }];